# When re-entering same url with Link Component in Next.js, prefetchQuery doesn't fetch data (SSR)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, client-side, react-query

I'm using Next.js and React Query for SSR.

Everything is fine until re-entering the exact dynamic route(e.g. `domain/support/guide/faq/[id]`).

The expected behavior is rendered query data without fetching as I used SSR for the component.

Please check my code

```js
// PAGE, I pass the query string to the <FAQContent /> Component

export default function FAQDetailPage({ id }: { id: string }) {

  return <FAQContent id={id} category={"faq"} />;
}

export async function getServerSideProps({
  query: { id },
}: {
  query: { id: string };
}) {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient();

  try {
    await queryClient.prefetchQuery(["support", "faq", id], () => {
      return sendRequest({
        method: "get",
        path: `/article/${id}`,
        apiType: "Contents",
      });
    });
  } catch (e) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: "/",
        permanent: false,
      },
    };
  }

  const dehydratedQueryClient = dehydrate(queryClient);

  const targetQuery = dehydratedQueryClient.queries[0];

  const targetQueryState = targetQuery.state as any;

  return {
    props: {
      dehydratedState: {
        ...dehydratedQueryClient,
        queries: [
          {
            ...dehydrate(queryClient).queries[0],
            state: {
              ...targetQueryState,
              data: targetQueryState.data.data,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      id,
    },
  };
}
```

```js
// Get id and category from the page, and pass to <SupportBoardContent />

export default function FAQContent({
  id,
  category,
}: {
  id: string;
  category: string;
}) {

  return <SupportBoardContent id={id} category={category} />;
}
```

```js
// Here is the component where hydrate the dehydrated query

export default function SupportBoardContent({
  id,
  category,
}: {
  id: string;
  category: string;
}) {
  const router = useRouter();

  const { pathname } = router;

  // This is a hook for useQuery.
  const {
    data: boardContent,
    ResponseHandler: ResponseHandlerOfGetBoardContent,
  } = SUPPORT_QUERY.useGetBoardContent({
    id,
    category,
  });

  const { title, contents, memo, videoURL, articleType } =
    boardContent?.targetArticle || {};


  return (
    <SupportLayout>

      {boardContent && (
        <CommonStyled.mainContainer>
          <SupportBreadcrumb title={title} />
          <BoardPageTitle titleStyle="default">
            {getArticleBoardTypeString(articleType)}
          </BoardPageTitle>
          <BoardContent
            title={title}
            annotation={memo}
            desc={contents}
            videoURL={videoURL}
          />
        </CommonStyled.mainContainer>
      )}
    </SupportLayout>
  );
}
```

When the component mounts on its first, nothings wrong. Everything works I expected. However, There is a `<SupportBreadCrumb />` Component.

In `<SupportBreadCrumb />`, I use `Link` from `Next/link`. Whenever I tries to enter the same page with `Link` Component, the `data` from `useQueryHook` is undefined.

**`id` is not undefined, `category` is not undefined. BUT data is undefined.**

I'm struggling with this problem for hours and need some guidance about it.

From this post, I want to know about:

1. Does using `Link` from Next.js is not a proper behavior when using SSR? By using `Link`, I heard that rendering of very first page is SSR condition, but does CSR afterword.
2. I want to know why `useQuery` doesn't fetch data, even `id` is ready for parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to your first question:
A link component in SSR always calls the `getServerSideProps` function, and this cannot be prevented. (It won't call when shallow routing is used).

A trick is to check whether the request to `getServerSideProps` is from a client side navigation and if so return an empty object for props and handle data fetching on the client.

Your second question : 
I am not sure what's going on and why your `useQuery` hook fails to fetch data, but your hydrate/dehydrate logic in your `getServerSideProps` is strange to me and I did not find any Hydrate component.
Maybe this is what is causing your problems.

I wrote a blog post about using [react-query and next.js SSR](https://dev.to/arianhamdi/react-query-v4-ssr-in-next-js-2ojj) and I hope it can help you.